# Separating a JSON string that contains object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a JSON string that contains an array and it is unable to be deserialized. I would like to split so that I can access a list of products and their codes and quantities, each time I try it crashes. The Json string is returned like so:

```
{
  "transaction_id": "88",
  "store_id": "3",
  "cashier_id": null,
  "loyalty_account": null,
  "transaction_time": "1382027452",
  "total_amount": "99.45",
  "items": {
    "1239219274": "1",
    "3929384913": "1"
  },
  "payments": {
    "cc": "99.45"
  }
}
```

I would like it to be separate it into:

```
{
  "transaction_id": "88",
  "store_id": "3",
  "cashier_id": null,
  "loyalty_account": null,
  "transaction_time": "1382027452",
  "total_amount": "99.45"
}
```

and

```
{
  "1239219274":"1",
  "3929384913":"1"
}
```

and

```
{
  "cc": "99.45"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated to reflect your edit.

That is not a JSON array, that is a JSON object which is basically a **dictionary** of values.

A JSON array is serialized like the following with square brackets **[ ]**:

```
{
    "name":"Outer Object",
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"Item #1"
        },
        {
            "name":"Item #2"
        },
        {
            "name":"Item #3"
        }
    ]
}
```

You should probably just spend a few minutes learning [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) which will take care of the details for you.

Here's how I can deserialize that string to an object:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [JsonProperty("transaction_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("store_id")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cashier_id")]
    public int? CashierId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("loyalty_account")]
    public string LoyaltyAccount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("transaction_time")]
    public int TransactionTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_amount")]
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("payments")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can simply write:

```
Transaction transaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Transaction>(json);
```

Comment: That is the result that comes directly from the database request. I have not formatted it at all. I understand that much, I just need to break down what I have there

Answer (score 2):

First of all you json string has an error you can validate it using an online validator like :
http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 9:
...   "1239219274": "1""3929384913": "1"  
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

And then for arrays they have this layout :

`a : [1,2,3,4,5]`

And using C# you can use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)
if using javascript you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)  or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/)

Comment: Check the edit I made a mistake I copied and pasted the wrong code

Comment: What do you mean by : `"items":{"1239219274":"1" "3929384913":"1"} this line is an array and I need to put all the values into a separate dictionar` ?