# Deserialize JSON dynamically named field with Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, json.net

I get answer in JSON format from server like this (uid1, uid2...uidN - is dynamically named fields from server):

```
{
   "get_message_state":
   {
      "uid1":"some text 1",
      "uid2":"some text 2",
      ...
      "uidN":"some text N"
   },
   "status":"OK_Operation_Completed"
}
```

When I try to describe a class to deserialize json response from server, i have a problem with **get_message_state** field. How to describe this field in class?

```
public class MessageStateResponse
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status", Order = 2)]
   public string Status { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "get_message_state", Order = 1)]
   public Msg MessageState { get; set; } //??????????
}

public class Msg
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; } //??????????
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: @mitomed if used code in first message, I don't have any errors, but  **get_message_state -> Fields** is null

Comment: Are you using Json.Net? There are quite a few answers that may help you if you refine the search, for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434500/deserializing-a-json-string-that-has-an-array-in-it Otherwise could you put how you're using it?

Comment: @mitomed thanks for the link, I found the answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wrap dictionary to `Msg` object.

```
public class MessageStateResponse
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status", Order = 2)]
   public string Status { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "get_message_state", Order = 1)] 
   public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I rewrite my code like this, it works. Thanks.